# Making a html kanban scrollable

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to create a [kanban board](https://github.com/jdiamond/html5-examples/blob/master/drag-and-drop/kanban.html), the code there seems great, but when a column(e.g ToDO) has a large number of items I use the browser scroll bar to scroll down, I would like to have a scroll bar visible for each swim lane, and be able to scroll a single swim lane so that I don't have to do the entire page.

I have tried adding overflow-y:scroll to the .section

```
    .section > h1 {
        margin: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 12pt;
        text-align: center;
        overflow-y:scroll;

    }
```

But this shows a scroll bar but I cannot scroll a single swim lane on its own. 
I'm completely new to HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the `overflow-y:scroll;` to the section class (`.section`), not only to the h1s in the class.

```
  .section {
        display: table-cell;
        margin: 0;
        border: 1px solid #666;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 300px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
```

what you did only makes the headlines scrollable if to big, not the entire thing. Maybe you should look at an explenation to the ">" in css